# How to set multiple cookies with setHeader in NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies

I have been working on a node js project, and I need to set two different cookies. But when I set them, the second one always overwrites the first one. here is the code I am using below

```
                              res.setHeader('set-cookie', [
                                'x-authsession=' + cookieParsed['x-authsession']
                                 + '; Path=' + cookieParsed['Path'] + '; Expires='
                                + cookieParsed['Expires']
                                + `;  `, ]
                                );
                            


                            res.setHeader('set-cookie', [
                                'x-device=' + cookieParsed['x-device']
                                + '; Path=' + cookieParsed['Path'] + '; Expires='
                                + cookieParsed['Expires']
                                + `; `,
                            ]);
```

but only x-device gets stored on the browser. Anyone knows how to fix this please?

Comment: Why don't you instead use `res.cookie()` function to set multiple cookies (by calling that multiple times)?

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer if it helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of explicitly modifying the `set-cookie` header you can use [`res.cookie`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.cookie).

```js
res.cookie(
    'x-authsession',
    cookieParsed['x-authsession'],
    {
        path: cookieParsed['Path'],
        expires: cookieParsed['Expires']
    }
);
res.cookie(
    'x-device',
    cookieParsed['x-device'],
    {
        path: cookieParsed['Path'],
        expires: cookieParsed['Expires']
    }
);
```

Also, as said [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie),

> To send multiple cookies, multiple Set-Cookie headers should be sent in the same response.

Side thoughts, looks like you are trying to use *session cookies* manually. That isn't a good idea to do. Instead checkout the `express-session` package on npm.

Answer (score 0):

this works fine for me:

```
res.setHeader("Set-Cookie", 
    [
    cookie.serialize("cookie1", "data1"),
    cookie.serialize("refreshToken", refreshToken)
    ]
)
res.end()
```